# Java Checkers with JButton matrix / killing piece is not working properly

Tags: java, swing, matrix, jbutton

I am trying to make a checkers game in Java. I made it with a Jbutton matrix [8][8]. However, when I kill a piece of the opponent this button becomes unavailable. I also check that in every move the button groups are checking for black, red, or white pieces.
Can someone help me figure it out?

Bellow is MyPanel Class

```
package checkers;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel{


    public MyPanel(){
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        board = new JPanel (new GridLayout(SIDE,SIDE));
        squares = new JButton[SIDE][SIDE];
        MoveJToggleButtonActionListener bh = new MoveJToggleButtonActionListener();

        for ( int i = 0; i < SIDE; i++ )
         {
            for ( int j = 0; j < SIDE; j++ )
            {
            // instantiate JButton array
               squares[i][j] = new JButton( );
               squares[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
            // make every other square red
               if ( ( i + j ) % 2 == 0  ){
                   squares[i][j].setBackground( MyPanel.white );
                   //doblank(i,j);
                   //blank.add(squares[i][j]);
               }

               if ( ( i + j ) % 2 != 0  )   
                  squares[i][j].setBackground( MyPanel.green );

               if(squares[i][j].getBackground()==MyPanel.green && i>=5){
                   squares[i][j].setIcon(p2Piece);
                   //squares[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                   //player2group.add(squares[i][j]);

               }
               if(squares[i][j].getBackground()==MyPanel.green && i<3){
                   //squares[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                   squares[i][j].setIcon(p1Piece);
                  // player1group.add(squares[i][j]);
               }



                   //blank.add(squares[i][j]);

               squares[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));         
            // add the JButton
               board.add( squares[i][j] );
            // register listener on button

               squares[i][j].addActionListener( bh );


            }
         }      


        p.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p);
    }



    private JPanel p,board;
    public static JButton[][] squares;
    public static int x;

    private MoveJToggleButtonActionListener moveaction;

    public static final int SIDE = 8;
    public static Icon p1Piece = new ImageIcon("G:\\Files\\tei\\Java_Arxes Texnologias Logismikou\\2020\\Final Project\\Java Checkers App\\Checkers\\icons\\pw.png");
    public static Icon p2Piece = new ImageIcon("G:\\Files\\tei\\Java_Arxes Texnologias Logismikou\\2020\\Final Project\\Java Checkers App\\Checkers\\icons\\pr.png");
    public static Color white = Color.decode("#ffffbb");
    public static Color green = Color.decode("#448866");
}
```

& the ActionListener Class

```
package checkers;

import static checkers.MyPanel.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class MoveJToggleButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{

    public MoveJToggleButtonActionListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        for ( int i = 0; i < SIDE; i++ )
            {
               for ( int j = 0; j < SIDE; j++ )
               {
                   if(squares[i][j].getIcon() != p1Piece && squares[i][j].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                       doblank(i,j);
                   else if(squares[i][j].getIcon() == p1Piece && squares[i][j].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                       player1group(i,j);
                   else if(squares[i][j].getIcon() == p2Piece && squares[i][j].getIcon() != p1Piece)
                       player2group(i,j);
               }
            }


        for ( int i = 0; i < SIDE; i++ )
            {
               for ( int j = 0; j < SIDE; j++ )
               {
                  if(ae.getSource() == squares[i][j] && squares[i][j].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                  {
                     //squares[i][j].setIcon(null);
                     System.out.println("RED : ["+i+"] ["+j+"]");


                     if(ae.getSource() == squares[i][j] && squares[i][j].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                     {
                         p2x=i;
                         p2y=j;

                         for(i=0; i<SIDE ;i++)
                         {
                             for(j=0 ;j<SIDE ;j++)
                             {
                                 squares[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                             }
                         }
                         if (p2y != 0 && p2y != 7)
                         {
                             if(squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("mprosta deksia exeis pouli");
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                            }
                            if(squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("mprosta aristera exeis pouli");
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                            }
                            if(squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].getIcon() == p2Piece && squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("No move");
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                            }
                            if(squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].getIcon() != p1Piece && squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("den exeis pouli mprosta sou");
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                                squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                            }
                            if(p2y!=6)
                            {
                                if(squares[p2x-1][p1y+1].getIcon() == p1Piece && squares[p2x-2][p2y+2].getIcon() == null)
                                {
                                squares[p2x-2][p2y+2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                                }
                            }
                            if(p2y!=1)
                            {
                                if(squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() == p1Piece && squares[p2x-2][p2y-2].getIcon() == null)
                                {
                                squares[p2x-2][p2y-2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                                }
                            } 

                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if(p2y == 0)
                             {
                                 if(squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                                     squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                             }
                             if(p2y == 7)
                             {
                                 if(squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                                     squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                             }
                         }

                     }

                  }



                  else if(ae.getSource() == squares[i][j] && squares[i][j].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                  {

                     System.out.println("WHITE : ["+i+"] ["+j+"]");

                     if(ae.getSource() == squares[i][j] && squares[i][j].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                     {
                         p1x=i;
                         p1y=j;

                         for(i=0; i<SIDE ;i++)
                         {
                             for(j=0 ;j<SIDE ;j++)
                             {
                                 squares[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                             }
                         }
                         if (p1y != 0 && p1y != 7)
                         {
                             if(squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("mprosta deksia exeis pouli");
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                            }
                            if(squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("mprosta aristera exeis pouli");
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                            }
                            if(squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() == p1Piece && squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("No move");
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                            }
                            if(squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() != p1Piece && squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() != p1Piece && squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() != p2Piece)
                            {
                                System.out.println("den exeis pouli mprosta sou");
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                                squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                            }

                            if(p1y!=6)
                            {
                                if(squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() == p2Piece && squares[p1x+2][p1y+2].getIcon() == null)
                                {
                                squares[p1x+2][p1y+2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                                }
                            }
                            if(p1y!=1)
                            {
                                if(squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() == p2Piece && squares[p1x+2][p1y-2].getIcon() == null)
                                {
                                squares[p1x+2][p1y-2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                                }
                            }                            

                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if(p1y == 0)
                             {
                                 if(squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() != p1Piece)
                                     squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                             }
                             if(p1y == 7)
                             {
                                 if(squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() != p1Piece)
                                     squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
                             }
                         }

                     }
                  }

                  else if(ae.getSource() == squares[i][j] && squares[i][j].getIcon() == null && squares[i][j].getBackground() != Color.white)
                  {

                     System.out.println("BLANK : ["+i+"] ["+j+"]");

                      if(i == p1x+1 && j == p1y-1)
                          domoveleftp1(p1x,p1y);
                      else if(i == p1x+1 && j == p1y+1)
                          domoverightp1(p1x,p1y);

                      if(i == p2x-1 && j == p2y-1)
                          domoveleftp2(p2x,p2y);
                      else if(i == p2x-1 && j == p2y+1)
                          domoverightp2(p2x,p2y);

                      if(i == p1x+2 && j == p1y-2 && squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                          doattackleftp1(p1x,p1y);
                      else if(i == p1x+2 && j == p1y+2 && squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                          doattackrightp1(p1x,p1y);

                      if(i == p2x-2 && j == p2y-2 && squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                          doattackleftp2(p2x,p2y);
                      else if(i == p2x-2 && j == p2y+2 && squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                          doattackrightp2(p2x,p2y);

                  }
               }
            }
        }

    private void dodisablep1() {
        for ( int x = 0; x < SIDE; x++ )
            {
               for ( int y = 0; y < SIDE; y++ )
               {
                   if(squares[x][y].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                        squares[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                   if(squares[x][y].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                        squares[x][y].setEnabled(true);
               }
            }
    }

    private void dodisablep2() {
        for ( int x = 0; x < SIDE; x++ )
            {
               for ( int y = 0; y < SIDE; y++ )
               {
                   if(squares[x][y].getIcon() == p2Piece)
                        squares[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                   if(squares[x][y].getIcon() == p1Piece)
                        squares[x][y].setEnabled(true);
               }
            }
    }


    private void domoveleftp1(int p1x, int p1y) {
        squares[p1x][p1y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setIcon(p1Piece);
        dodisablep1();
    }
    private void domoverightp1(int p1x, int p1y) {
        squares[p1x][p1y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setIcon(p1Piece);
        dodisablep1();
    }
    private void domoveleftp2(int p2x, int p2y) {
        squares[p2x][p2y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setIcon(p2Piece);
        dodisablep2();
    }
    private void domoverightp2(int p2x, int p2y) {
        squares[p2x][p2y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setIcon(p2Piece);
        dodisablep2();
    }

    private void doattackrightp1(int p1x, int p1y) {
        squares[p1x+1][p1y+1].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x][p1y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x+2][p1y+2].setIcon(p1Piece);
        dodisablep1();
    }

    private  void doattackleftp1(int p1x, int p1y) {
        squares[p1x+1][p1y-1].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x][p1y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p1x+2][p1y-2].setIcon(p1Piece);
        dodisablep1();
    }

    private void doattackrightp2(int p2x, int p2y) {
        squares[p2x-1][p2y+1].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x][p2y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x-2][p2y+2].setIcon(p2Piece);
        dodisablep2();
    }

    private  void doattackleftp2(int p2x, int p2y) {
        squares[p2x-1][p2y-1].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x][p2y].setIcon(null);
        squares[p2x-2][p2y-2].setIcon(p2Piece);
        dodisablep2();
    }

    ButtonGroup blank = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup player1group = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup player2group = new ButtonGroup();

    public void doblank(int i, int j)
    {
        blank.add(squares[i][j]);
    }

    public void player1group(int i, int j)
    {
        player1group.add(squares[i][j]);
    }

    public void player2group(int i, int j)
    {
        player2group.add(squares[i][j]);
    }

    public int i,j;
    public int p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y;
    private JButton button;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the main method?  How can the code be compiled and executed for testing?

Comment: I would suggest put a breakpoint in the method setEnabled() of JButton and see in debug mode where is the call coming from.

Comment: You have posted over 400 lines of code.  Please consider creating a [reprex] to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong you are totally right. However, at this point all the above seems to be necessary for the app.
Maybe I can clarify a little bit how it works. 

At the JPanel (MyPanel) I create the 8 x 8 JButton Matrix & place icons for the Pieces. Also, I call the MoveJToggleButtonActionListener bh when a button is selected.

That's all.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong In MoveJToggleButtonActionListener class, I scan all pieces with a nested for and categorize the JButton to 3 Button Groups. blank (No piece), player1group (player 1 pieces) & player2group (player 2 pieces).

In another nested loop:
With multiple if, I indicate the allowed moves of a JButton when clicked.
Furthermore, I check the selected JButton pressed & the next one (Blank) & call the methods to move (move 1 piece diagonally) or attack (move 2 pieces diagonally and set the previous to NULL).

I this the issue is at the methods doattackrightp1,doattackrightp2, etc.

Comment: @NormR the main method just call a JFrame that host the above JPanel.


You can find my code so far at the following dropbox link:


[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpqx2vrk8sulzyx/Java%20Checkers%20App.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Well I'm not sure I can debug your whole program, but I can tell you that the `dodisablepx()` methods are the only place I see buttons being disabled, so I recommend using debug mode and seeing when those methods are being called.  Also, I don't mean to be pushy, but I think you should actually take some time to read the page I linked to above.  It has a really good explanation of how to debug code and trim it down if the bug still persists.  Also consider giving [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read.

Comment: Where in the code is a captured piece removed?  I can't read the comments.

Comment: @NormR the methods for capturing a piece are at the MoveJToggleButtonActionListener Class  (doattackrightp1, doattackrightp2, doattackleftp2 & doattackleftp1).These methods are called at the last if-else condition of public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae).

Comment: All squares start enabled. Switching sides disables the other side's squares.  
If a man from the other side is captured, the square it was on is not enabled when sides switch again.  There needs to be some logic to enable that square.

Comment: @NormR You are totally right. I just create another disable button method when pieces captured (not the same as just moving) and left the captured button enabled for 1 round. Works like charm!! Thank you very much